# Is this map of the galaxy valid according to Stargate SG-1?

Tags: stargate-sg1, stargate

I've found a galaxy map on the internet. And I am curious, if it is valid according to Stargate SG-1.

I cannot remember any episode where a galaxy map is shown with labels.

[image]

Comment: It might be useful if you quoted your source rather than just "the internet". **Where** on the internet?

Comment: I haven't quoted the source, because it was a result of a google search. It can be found on many fan sites. For example here: http://janekblog.blog.cz/en/category/mapa-galaxie

Answer (score 13):

### Is it official or fan-made?

This map is definitely fan-made. It doesn't appear in any episodes or tie-in media. Using a reverse image search, I could only find this image on Reddit and imgur, not an official or licensed Stargate site.

### Is it accurate, despite being fan-made?

I was a little skeptical going into this because the shows never said where most of these planets are. The show said that Abydos is the closest planet to Earth, but not where the Nox homeworld is.

Some of the political boundaries are suspect too. Right next to the label "Former Ra's territory" is Cartego, which was instead ruled by the Goa'uld Pelops, and BP6-3Q1 (Svoriin), which was never discovered by the Goa'uld. I also find it hard to believe that the Aschen were surrounded by "former Goa'uld systems" and "former Ra's territory", yet had never encountered them.

Also near Tollan is marked "Former Oaness territory". There was a race called the *[Oannes](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ohne)* (note the different spelling), but they had nothing to do with the Tollan. This other spelling was propogated by an online Czech Stargate fan game at http://oaness.wz.cz. I suspect that this map was made for that game, but couldn't find out for sure.

#### Bottom line, there is no official information about these planets' locations and there are enough mistakes and head scratchers to doubt that it's anything more than entirely made up.

Comment: There are also these pages [1](http://www.fan-project.net/viewtopic.php?f=60&t=5412&start=50) [2](http://www.sgo.uvadi.cz/index.php?page=galerie), for another Czech SG fan game, which contain the same map with additional watermark. I can't tell which version is the original. (Translation of the forum post is: "And finally, I could release this too, most authors haven't seen it yet anyway …".)

Comment: Also, how is Abydos NOT contained in "former Ra's territory" when Ra was the very Goa'uld in control of that planet during the original Stargate movie?

Comment: @Steve-O Yeah, I wondered about that too, but given that the borders of "former Ra's territory" are not well defined, I figured it was at least plausible that his territory was widespread and that Abydos was on the edge of it.